# Sxa search box suggested result not found in multisite scenario

Tags: sxa, multisite, sxa-search

**Context**: I am using the **sxa search box component** in site A to search through the items of site B, which is a *shared* site.
The search itself it is working fine: when I click enter, it shows the results page of site B, as required. Also the search box drop-down is showing the right suggestions.

**Issue**: when clicking on a suggestion in the drop-down I get a 404, since the link of the suggestion does not contain the domain of the site B and the item is not found on site A.

**Question**: it is possible to add the domain to the link of the suggestion in order to manage this multisite scenario or is there another way of doing this?

I have tried to set the field *Suggestions mode* to *Show search results as predictions* but the required behaviour is to link directly to the item when clicking on the suggestion, not to go to the results page.

Thanks for any advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom rendering variant for `Search box` to get rendered html for suggestions. By default it uses *horizontal*, you can create a new for example *horizontal-absoluteurl*.

[image: Custom Rendering Variant For Search Box with Absolute Url - Sitecore SXA]
[image: Rendered Html via Rendering Variant]
*Image: How you can check what html is rendered for the item via your rendering variant*

Scriban have parameter to get url `{{i_item.url }}` see if that works, if not you will need to create custom scriban extension like `{{i_item.url_absolute}}`.

The custom scriban extension which will have your c# logic for getting absolute url for item by detecting its related site context (by matching path or any other logic you want).

You can refer this blog creating scriban extension: https://www.dotnet-ltd.com/blog/create-item-extension-with-scriban

```
<div class="field-title your-custom-rv-for-absolute-url"><a title="{{i_item.Title}}" href="{{i_item.url_absolute}}">{{ sc_field i_item "__Display Name" }}</a></div>
```

Note: I'm sharing the idea, but it hasn't been tested yet.

Hope this helpful!